# On value changes, change the internal form values

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a createForm and updateForm in same component. When `updateForm = true` I need to set the value of my `initVal` and `ongoingVal` initially from response data. With current function `oncustomerUpdate()` it works fine, But when I change the value in `this.createBizFormGroup.controls.customerDetails.get('custType’)` in updateForm, the values in `initVal` and `ongoingVal` should be reset to `[]` and new options will be populated in dropdown, on selecting the new value it will set the values to initVal and ongoingVal. But Now when changing the value it is giving empty chip,but existing value is still there in empty mat-chip. I know this is because of the following line of code in setOptions()
    `if (this.updateForm) {       const initialDataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initialData))         this.formGroup.setControl('ongoingVal', this.formBuilder.control(initialDataCopy?.ongoingVal))         this.formGroup.setControl('initVal', this.formBuilder.control(initialDataCopy?.initVal))     }` because of this, even when I reset the value,initialData is stored in and not clearing and added with new values. oncustTypeChange() is function used in createForm which works as expected. Please help with a soltution

```
    @Input() this.originalcustType : string| undefined // value from parent 
               updateForm = false
              setOptions(custType: string) {
             const custTypeMap = custTypeMapping[custType] || ''
              if (this.custType && custTypeMap && custTypeMap === this.custType) {
               return
              }
              this.custType = custTypeMap
              this.formGroup.get('initVal')?.setValue('')
              this.formGroup.get('ongoingVal')?.setValue('')
              if (this.updateForm) {
             const initialDataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initialData))
             this.formGroup.setControl('ongoingVal', 
             this.formBuilder.control(initialDataCopy?.ongoingVal))
             this.formGroup.setControl('initVal',                    
            this.formBuilder.control(initialDataCopy?.initVal))
          }
           if (custTypeMap) {
             this.initialOptions = this.ValTypeMappingOptions[custTypeMap + 'Initial']
              this.ongoingOptions = this.ValTypeMappingOptions[custTypeMap + 'Ongoing']
            } else {
             this.initialOptions = []
              this.ongoingOptions = []
             }
             }
 
             oncustomerUpdate() {
            const custType = 
          this.createBizFormGroup.controls.customerDetails.get('custType')?.value
          if (custType) {
           this.disableOptions = false
            } else {
              this.disableOptions = true
              }
           this.setOptions(custType)
            }
 
          oncustTypeChange() {
 this.createForm.controls.customerDetails.get('custType')?.valueChanges.subscribe((custType) => {
      if (custType) {
        this.disableOptions = false
      } else {
        this.disableOptions = true
      }
      this.setOptions(custType)
    })
  }
```